# Element inside Element in XSD file is not generated

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to add element inside an element in XSD file.
When I am trying to do it I received the error:
**[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_nodeosm' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
  line 32 of file:/D:/.../src/conf/xml-resources/jaxb/generated/scheme.xsd**

The error started when I added `<xs:element name="edge".... </xs:element>`
Without this it works fine.

**What I want to do:**
Class Edge that will be inner class in Node class.
I also want class Node to have member `List<Edge> m_Edges`, I am not sure how to do it.
I tried to do it similar to the XSD elements that worked but without success.

**My XSD file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="osm">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bounds">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="minlat" />
                                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="minlon" />
                                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="maxlat" />
                                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="maxlon" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="node" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="tag" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="k" use="optional" />
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="v" use="optional" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>          
                        </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="edge" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:node" name="source" use="optional" />
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:node" name="destination" use="optional" />
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:double" name="weight" use="optional" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                        <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="id" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="visible" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="version" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="changeset" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="timestamp" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="user" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="uid" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="lat" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="lon" use="optional" />

                    </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>


                <xs:element name="way" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="nd" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="ref" use="optional" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="tag" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="k" use="optional" />
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="v" use="optional" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="visible" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="version" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="changeset" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="timestamp" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="user" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="uid" use="optional" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="relation" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="member" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="optional" />
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:long" name="ref" use="optional" />
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="role" use="optional" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="tag" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="k" use="optional" />
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="v" use="optional" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="visible" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="version" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="changeset" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="timestamp" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="user" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="uid" use="optional" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="version" />
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="generator" />
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="copyright" />
            <xs:attribute type="xs:anyURI" name="attribution" />
            <xs:attribute type="xs:anyURI" name="license" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to generate class Node that will contain class Edge like this:

```
public class Edge {

    Node m_Source;
    Node m_Destination;

    double m_Weight;

    public Edge(Node i_Source, Node i_Destination, double i_Weight) {
        m_Source = i_Source;
        m_Destination = i_Destination;
        m_Weight = i_Weight;
    }

    public Node getSource() {
        return m_Source;
    }

    public Node getDestination() {
        return m_Destination;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return m_Weight;
    }


    public void setSource(Node i_SourceNode)
    {
        m_Source = i_SourceNode;
    }

    public void setDestination(Node i_DestinationNode)
    {
        m_Destination = i_DestinationNode;
    }
}
```

**XSD solution without errors (after following Andreas's answer):**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error "started when [you] added `<xs:element name="edge".... </xs:element>`", which is line 32 like the error message says.

You added the element outside the `<xs:sequence>` tag. Move the inserted element one line up.

This assumes that you wanted `<node>` to contain two elements: `<tag>` and `<edge>` (in that order).

Comment: When I tried it I receive error: 
[ERROR] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:node'. It was detected that 'xs:node' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/D:/.../scheme.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:node' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/D:/.../scheme.xsd'.
  line 33 of file:/D:/.../scheme.xsd

Comment: There is no `xs:node` datatype. See [XML Schema Datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes). Your attributes `source` and `destination` try to use that type. The error message shows the line number and the offending name. What more do you need?

Comment: I have  <xs:element name="node"...> , it doesn't make it xs:node datatype?

Comment: That defines an "element", not a "type", and not in the `xs` namespace.

Comment: OK, I defined it for now as string type and it works. I will check regarding customize types but this is another issue.